# How to Create Content Remotely

Tags: wp-insert-post, remote

I'm trying to help populate a newly setup wordpress website and am trying to write scripts to do automated posting of a pre-processed archive of e-mails as a series of posts and comments. I'm completely new to wordpress development and would like to be able to use the wp_insert_post and wp_insert_comment from my remote machine to achieve this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/), *WordPress Command Line Interface*. If your pre-processed archive is a set of files, you'll be able to create `future` posts to be published on specified dates utilizing these files in batch.

All you need to use WP-CLI remotely is *SSH terminal* and, maybe, some scripting skills.

[See also](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/09/wordpress-management-with-wp-cli/) Smashing Magazine review.